# How to improve the calibration of my image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to add a function with trackbars to calibrate in order to detect specific (or as wished) shape. The trackbars should calibrate HSV and Threshold.

Here is my code, but it only detects perfect shapes in perfect lighting and doesn't recognise anything if the lighting isn't perfect. This needs to be installed on a drone so this will be capturing videos from almost 100ft and should be able to detect shapes and capture image.

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
import time
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="path to the video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

def nothing(x):
    print x
    pass

count=0                         #Initializing count to 0, which will be used for naming the captured frame.

# load the video
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
#camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)                             #For live feed from External Camera
# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame and initialize the status text
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    status = "No Targets/Waypoint"

    # check to see if we have reached the end of the
    # video
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # convert the frame to grayscale, blur it, and detect edges
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)

    # find contours in the edge map
    _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # loop over the contours
    for c in contours:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True)

        # ensure that the approximated contour is "roughly" rectangular
        if len(approx) >= 3 and len(approx) <= 6:
            # compute the bounding box of the approximated contour and
            # use the bounding box to compute the aspect ratio
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            aspectRatio = w / float(h)

            # compute the solidity of the original contour
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            hullArea = cv2.contourArea(cv2.convexHull(c))
            solidity = area / float(hullArea)

            # compute whether or not the width and height, solidity, and
            # aspect ratio of the contour falls within appropriate bounds
            keepDims = w > 25 and h > 25
            keepSolidity = solidity > 0.9
            keepAspectRatio = aspectRatio >= 0.8 and aspectRatio <= 1.2

            # ensure that the contour passes all our tests
            if keepDims and keepSolidity and keepAspectRatio:
                # draw an outline around the target and update the status
                # text
                cv2.drawContours(frame, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)
                status = "Target(s)/Waypoint(s) Acquired"

                # compute the center of the contour region and draw the
                # crosshairs
                time.sleep(0.04)
                M = cv2.moments(approx)
                (cX, cY) = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
                (startX, endX) = (int(cX - (w * 0.15)), int(cX + (w * 0.15)))
                (startY, endY) = (int(cY - (h * 0.15)), int(cY + (h * 0.15)))
                cv2.line(frame, (startX, cY), (endX, cY), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                cv2.line(frame, (cX, startY), (cX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                success,image = camera.read()                   ########################################################
                print 'Read a new frame: ', success
                cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
                count += 1  
                time.sleep(1.5)                                             ###############################
    # draw the status text on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, status, (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
        (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # show the frame and record if a key is pressed
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What image processing features can I use in which we can calibrate for the HSV and threshold and save the values for the threshold we require for our images?

For example, in this image pysquares(in black) can be detected due to good lighting but this code cannot find contours if lighting isn't as much as it is in this, I want a calibration function in which we can calibrate HSV values and Threshold value to make the program understand the required figure.

[image]

Comment: Does a simple batch-norm process solve your problem?  Scale all pixels to have mean brightness in the middle of your representation range, and a sane standard deviation.  Alternately, scale so that the darkest pixels are just barely pure black, and the lightest are just barely pure white, with everything else scaled linearly in between.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).